# Ran into this error: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered when running a colab notebook, how can i fix it?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, multiclass-classification, image-classification

I'm running code listed in here: https://github.com/Omid-Nejati/MedViT/blob/main/Colab_MedViT.ipynb
In this step

```
`data_flag = 'breastmnist'
# [tissuemnist, pathmnist, chestmnist, dermamnist, octmnist, 
# pnemoniamnist, retinamnist, breastmnist, bloodmnist, tissuemnist, organamnist, organcmnist, organsmnist]
download = True

NUM_EPOCHS = 10
BATCH_SIZE = 10
lr = 0.005

info = INFO[data_flag]
task = info['task']
n_channels = info['n_channels']
n_classes = len(info['label'])

DataClass = getattr(medmnist, info['python_class'])`
```

When i change breastmnist to dermamnist i get an error in the training step
how can i fix this?

My guess is the problem is with this code

```
if task == "multi-label, binary-class":
    criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
else:
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=lr, momentum=0.9)
```

since the dermamnist dataset is multi-class but I'm not experienced enough to figure out how to fix it

And thanks in advance